# Product in box topology and product topology

Tags: general-topology

Is the following conjecture true ? I am trying to collect some properties about box topology and product topology in order to study for topology exam.

is the product of connected compact space connected in the box topology?

Comment: No: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529550/connected-components-in-box-topology) and its answer.

Comment: Could you give me explicit example ?

Comment: I guess one example would be $[0,2]^{\omega}$ that is not connected right ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott did you notice compact ?

Comment: Yes. Just replace $\Bbb R$ by $[0,1]$; essentially the same argument works.

Comment: But using his argument why is then $[0,1]^{\omega}$ not connected ?

Comment: If the space were connected, it would be the component of every point. The argument shows that this is not the case: the component of a point is very much smaller than the whole space. Therefore the space is not connected.

Comment: ok that is great I understand now !