# Connectedness of $\mathbb R^\omega$ in different topologies

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, topological-vector-spaces

Is $\mathbb R^\omega$ with box topology connected? Is it connected in uniform topology? It is connected with product topology. But I don't know the case for box and uniform topology.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your answer.it seems to me union of all such sets ${0}×⋯×{0}×\mathbb R×{0}…$ is not$\mathbb R^w$ but it is             
  $\mathbb R^\infty$. Closure of${0}×⋯×{0}×$$ \mathbb R$$×{0}…$ is $R^w$ in product topology but not in box topology ..hence your argument is valid for product topology but not for box topology.

Answer (score 1):

In order to mark the question as answered, I say that  [$\Bbb R^\omega$ is disconnected in the uniform topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/300221/71850), and so also in a stronger box topology. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669212/what-are-the-components-and-path-components-of-mathbbr-omega-in-the-prod) answer for more.